# modal vertical position center

Tags: css, angular

1.How to put a modal in the center?

2.Using Angular 2/4 with html5,JS and css!

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Deseja excluir definitivamente?</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Confirmar Ação" (click)="c('Close click')" (click)="deleteUser(user)">Confirmar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Cancelar Ação" (click)="c('Close click')">Cancelar</button>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
```

Comment: Is it a fixed height modal?

Comment: I got this example ready, I do not know

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Deseja excluir definitivamente?</h4>
            </div>
            <!--add this in start here--><div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p><!--end here-->
  </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Confirmar Ação" (click)="c('Close click')" (click)="deleteUser(user)">Confirmar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" title="Cancelar Ação" (click)="c('Close click')">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, just add the modal body into the middle of you code as above. add you content in-between the p tags. I hope this answers your question. If not, hit me back.

Comment: Please add this additional information in your answer itself and not as a comment.

Comment: my problem is to put the whole modal in the center of the screen,because it is fixed at the top.

Answer (score 0):

AS per your requirement your modal should be in fixed height, so based on that you can set top margin and other css.

**OR**

You have to calculate modal height after DOM/HTML render in your modal body and then again apply some calculation logic and set top-margin from back end.